# Webscraping HTML tables to retrieve data from a column of each row using Selenium Webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to scrape data from classic.clinicaltrials.gov and get the Study title, conditions, and the interventions of each study in the table and save it into an excel sheet.
I am not able to get the data of this
Please refer to https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist=
to get the html of the table in which the data is situated

I tried this code to receive just the list of conditions but I am unable to do so.

```
from selenium import webdriver 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
driver = webdriver.Chrome() 
URL = "https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist="
driver.get(URL)
table_body = driver.find_element(By .XPATH, '//[@id="theDataTable"]/tbody') 
rows = table_body.find_elements(By .XPATH, '//[@id="theDataTable"]/tbody/tr') 
print(table_body) 
for row in rows: 
    req_rows = row.find_elements(By .CSS_SELECTOR, '[role="row"]') 
    for cell in req_rows:
        req_cells = req_rows.find_elements(By .TAG_NAME, 'td') 
        for conditions in req_cells.find_elements(By .TAG_NAME, 'li'): 
            print(conditions.text) 

driver.quit()
```

this code is just giving no output and I am really trying hard to get the result please help me!

Comment: [try using selenium explicit wait](https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/waits/#explicit-wait). Also, your xpath for table is wrong try using `//*[@id="theDataTable"]`. You can get xpath by simply `right-click` -> `copy` -> `copy xpath` on dev-tools

Answer (score 0):

Here is the list of issues that you have:

1. you have to specify element tag before `[@id="theDataTable"]`
2. you have a typo in the variable name `conditions`
3. the locator for the condition cells is not correct

Here is the updated code, hope it works:

```py
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
URL = "https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist="

driver.get(URL)

table_body = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '//table[@id="theDataTable"]/tbody')
rows = table_body.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'tr')

for row in rows:
    condition_cells = row.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'td')[2]
    conditions = condition_cells.find_elements(By.TAG_NAME, 'li')
    for condition in conditions:
        print(condition.text)

driver.quit()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Check the full working code below:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC


driver = webdriver.Chrome()
URL = "https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results?cond=&term=&cntry=&state=&city=&dist="
driver.get(URL)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 30)
time.sleep(5)
study_title = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='theDataTable']//td[4]")))
conditions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='theDataTable']//td[5]")))
interventions = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='theDataTable']//td[6]")))

study_title = [element.text for element in study_title]
conditions = [element.text for element in conditions]
interventions = [element.text for element in interventions]

print(study_title)
print(conditions)
print(interventions)
```

**Console Result:**

```
['Quality of Life, Functional Outcomes and Costs in Shoulder Arthroplasty', 'Inotuzumab Ozogamicin in the Treatment of MRD+ After HSCT of ALL', '[Trial of device that is not approved or cleared by the U.S. FDA]', 'The Relationship of Developing Metabolic Acidosis With Antiepleptic Drugs in Craniotomy Operations', 'RWE-based Treatment Patterns and Outcomes in CIDP', 'Bioequivalence Study of Perindopril /Amlodipine/Indapamide 8 mg (10 mg)/2.5 mg/10 mg Tablets in Healthy Volunteers Under Fasting Conditions', 'RC48-ADC Combined With Radiotherapy in the Treatment of Locally Advanced Solid Tumors With HER2 Expression', 'A Study to Evaluate the Pharmacokinetics,Safety and Tolerability of Y-2 Sublingual Tablet in Healthy Adult Subjects', 'A Prospective Post-marketing Observational Study Assessing the Safety and Efficacy of Nerivio for Migraine Prevention.', 'Sponsor-Initiated OCS Liver Perfusion (OLP-II) Registry']
['Shoulder Arthropathy', 'MRD-positive After HSCT of ALL Patients', '', 'Metabolic Acidosis\nAntiepileptic Drugs\nCraniotomy\nAnesthesia Management', 'Chronic Inflammatory Demyelinating Polyneuropathy\nGuillain-Barre Syndrome\nHereditary Amyloidosis', 'Bioequivalence', 'Solid Tumor', 'Healthy', 'Migraine', 'Liver Transplant']
['Other: Questionnaire administration', 'Drug: Inotuzumab Ozogamicin', '', 'Procedure: Arterial Blood Gas Base Deficit', 'Other: No intervention. Retrospective observation only.', 'Drug: Perindopril/Indapamide/Amlodipine 8 mg/2.5 mg/10 mg tablet / Triplixam® 10 mg/2.5 mg/10 mg tablet', 'Drug: Disitamab vedotin', 'Drug: Y-2 Sublingual Tablet\nDrug: Placebo', 'Device: Nerivio', 'Device: OCS Liver']

Process finished with exit code 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I'd go the path and getting the data from the POST. Then parse out the html:

the payload is a bit long, but this should be quicker, and will get you more info:

For example, first few rows:

```
print(df.head().to_string())
    0            1                      2                                                                                                                   3                                                                                         4                                                                5               6               7                                                                                                                                               8         9                                                                                                                                        10                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        11   12   13                                                   14           15               16        17                  18                 19                 20            21            22 23                                                                                                                                                   24 25
0  801  NCT05930574           CompletedNew  Implementation of an Epidemiological and Clinical Registry of Emergency Surgery Patients in a Costa Rican Hospital                                                          Surgical ComplicationEmergencies                                     Procedure: Abdominal surgery   Observational                                                                                                                             Caja Costarricense de Seguro Social     Other                                                                          Observational Model: Case-OnlyTime Perspective: Cross-Sectional                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                               MortalityMechanical ventilationRequirement of Intensive Care UnitInfections  575  All  12 Years to 100 Years   (Child, Adult, Older Adult)  NCT05930574  01-UIS-HCG-2023                   May 1, 2020  November 30, 2020  December 31, 2022  July 5, 2023  July 5, 2023                                                        Unidad de Investigación en Salud, Hospital Dr. Rafael Angel Calderón GuardiaSan José, Costa Rica   
1  802  NCT05930561  Not yet recruitingNew                                                                      4D-150 in Patients With Diabetic Macular Edema                                                Diabetic Macular EdemaDiabetic Retinopathy                Biological: 4D-150 IVTBiological: Aflibercept IVT  Interventional         Phase 2                                                                                                                       4D Molecular Therapeutics  Industry  Allocation: RandomizedIntervention Model: Parallel AssignmentMasking: Double (Participant, Outcomes Assessor)Primary Purpose: Treatment                                                                                                                                         Annualized number of aflibercept injections in the study eyeMean cumulative number of aflibercept injections over timeChange from baseline in BCVA as assessed using the ETDRS Visual Acuity Chart(and 2 more...)   72  All            18 Years and older   (Adult, Older Adult)  NCT05930561      4D-150-C002            September 30, 2023  February 29, 2028       July 1, 2028  July 5, 2023  July 5, 2023                                                                                                                                                           
2  803  NCT05930548  Not yet recruitingNew     Evaluation of Giomer Composite Versus Resin-Modified Glass Ionomer in Cervical Caries Lesions: A Clinical Trial                                                                          Caries, Cervical                                      Other: Low Shrinkage Giomer  Interventional  Not Applicable                                                                                                                                Cairo University     Other  Allocation: RandomizedIntervention Model: Parallel AssignmentMasking: Double (Participant, Outcomes Assessor)Primary Purpose: Treatment                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                      Clinical performance   56  All                16 Years to 55 Years   (Child, Adult)  NCT05930548         LSG_RMGI             September 1, 2023     April 30, 2025     April 30, 2025  July 5, 2023  July 5, 2023                                                                                                                                                           
3  804  NCT05930535  Not yet recruitingNew                                                               Family-Focused Adolescent & Lifelong Health Promotion  Adolescent BehaviorAdolescent - Emotional ProblemPsychological Well-Being(and 2 more...)  Behavioral: Parenting for Lifelong Health for Parents and Teens  Interventional  Not Applicable  University of KlagenfurtInstitute for Marriage, Family and Systemic Practice - ALTERNATIVAHealth for Youth Association, Moldova(and 5 more...)     Other                          Allocation: N/AIntervention Model: Single Group AssignmentMasking: None (Open Label)Primary Purpose: Prevention  Change in levels of adolescent emotional problems: Revised Child Anxiety and Depression Scales (RCADS), subscalesChange in levels of adolescent emotional problems: Child Behavior Checklist (CBCL) 6-18, internalizing subscaleChange in levels of adolescent emotional problems: Youth Self-Report (YSR) 11-18, internalizing subscale(and 15 more...)  120  All                       10 Years to 14 Years   (Child)  NCT05930535        101095528  FLOURISH      September 2023         March 2024         March 2024  July 5, 2023  July 5, 2023     Health For Youth AssociationChisinau, Moldova, Republic ofInstitute for Marriage, Family and Systemic Practice - ALTERNATIVASkopje, North Macedonia   
4  805  NCT05930522           CompletedNew                                                                          Psychomotor Performance of Preterm Infants                                                          Psychomotor Development Impaired                                                                    Observational                                                                                                               Gdansk University of Physical Education and Sport     Other                                                                                 Observational Model: CohortTime Perspective: Prospective                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                           Eurofit testBiodex Balance System SDVienna Test  180  All                         7 Years to 9 Years   (Child)  NCT05930522  AWFiS/2023_3_PE               October 1, 2018   February 1, 2020     March 30, 2020  July 5, 2023  July 5, 2023                                                                              Gdansk University of Physical Education and SportGdańsk, Pomorskie, Poland
```

**Full Code:**

```
import requests
import math
import pandas as pd
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = "https://classic.clinicaltrials.gov/ct2/results/rpc/Yi0n"

payload = {
'draw': '3',
'columns[0][data]': '0',
'columns[0][name]': '',
'columns[0][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[0][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[0][search][value]': '',
'columns[0][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[1][data]': '1',
'columns[1][name]': '',
'columns[1][searchable]': 'false',
'columns[1][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[1][search][value]': '',
'columns[1][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[2][data]': '2',
'columns[2][name]': '',
'columns[2][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[2][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[2][search][value]': '',
'columns[2][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[3][data]': '3',
'columns[3][name]': '',
'columns[3][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[3][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[3][search][value]': '',
'columns[3][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[4][data]': '4',
'columns[4][name]': '',
'columns[4][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[4][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[4][search][value]': '',
'columns[4][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[5][data]': '5',
'columns[5][name]': '',
'columns[5][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[5][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[5][search][value]': '',
'columns[5][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[6][data]': '6',
'columns[6][name]': '',
'columns[6][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[6][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[6][search][value]': '',
'columns[6][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[7][data]': '7',
'columns[7][name]': '',
'columns[7][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[7][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[7][search][value]': '',
'columns[7][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[8][data]': '8',
'columns[8][name]': '',
'columns[8][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[8][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[8][search][value]': '',
'columns[8][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[9][data]': '9',
'columns[9][name]': '',
'columns[9][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[9][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[9][search][value]': '',
'columns[9][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[10][data]': '10',
'columns[10][name]': '',
'columns[10][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[10][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[10][search][value]': '',
'columns[10][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[11][data]': '11',
'columns[11][name]': '',
'columns[11][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[11][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[11][search][value]': '',
'columns[11][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[12][data]': '12',
'columns[12][name]': '',
'columns[12][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[12][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[12][search][value]': '',
'columns[12][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[13][data]': '13',
'columns[13][name]': '',
'columns[13][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[13][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[13][search][value]': '',
'columns[13][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[14][data]': '14',
'columns[14][name]': '',
'columns[14][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[14][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[14][search][value]': '',
'columns[14][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[15][data]': '15',
'columns[15][name]': '',
'columns[15][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[15][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[15][search][value]': '',
'columns[15][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[16][data]': '16',
'columns[16][name]': '',
'columns[16][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[16][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[16][search][value]': '',
'columns[16][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[17][data]': '17',
'columns[17][name]': '',
'columns[17][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[17][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[17][search][value]': '',
'columns[17][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[18][data]': '18',
'columns[18][name]': '',
'columns[18][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[18][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[18][search][value]': '',
'columns[18][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[19][data]': '19',
'columns[19][name]': '',
'columns[19][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[19][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[19][search][value]': '',
'columns[19][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[20][data]': '20',
'columns[20][name]': '',
'columns[20][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[20][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[20][search][value]': '',
'columns[20][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[21][data]': '21',
'columns[21][name]': '',
'columns[21][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[21][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[21][search][value]': '',
'columns[21][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[22][data]': '22',
'columns[22][name]': '',
'columns[22][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[22][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[22][search][value]': '',
'columns[22][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[23][data]': '23',
'columns[23][name]': '',
'columns[23][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[23][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[23][search][value]': '',
'columns[23][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[24][data]': '24',
'columns[24][name]': '',
'columns[24][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[24][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[24][search][value]': '',
'columns[24][search][regex]': 'false',
'columns[25][data]': '25',
'columns[25][name]': '',
'columns[25][searchable]': 'true',
'columns[25][orderable]': 'false',
'columns[25][search][value]': '',
'columns[25][search][regex]': 'false',
'start': '0',
'length': '100',
'search[value]': '',
'search[regex]': 'false'
}


jsonData = requests.post(URL, data=payload).json()
total_records = jsonData['recordsTotal']
total_pages = math.ceil(int(total_records)/100)

data = jsonData['data']
print(f'Page: 1 of {total_pages}')
for page in range(1, total_pages+1):
    next_start = 100*page
    payload.update({'start': '%s' %next_start})
    print(f'Page: {page+1} of {total_pages}')
    jsonData = requests.post(URL, data=payload).json()
    data += jsonData['data']


df = pd.DataFrame(data)

def extract_text(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'html.parser')
    return soup.get_text()


for col in df.columns:
    df[col] = df[col].apply(extract_text)


df_alpha = df[[3, 4, 5]]
df_alpha.columns = ['Study Title', 'Conditions', 'Interventions']
```